# Evolution the Beginning - Scavenger card

Tags: evolution

When a scavenger is given food tokens during a carnivore attack, does the scavenger get to keep all the food tokens, even though that scavenger does not have enough "room" for all the food -- e.g., enough population or a fat tissue card?

(We understand that the tokens stay with the scavenger until the end of the scavenger's own turn, or until the scavenger is made extinct.)

The rules do not seem to restrict a scavenger to only so many food tokens as the scavenger has "room" to eat.

[ In contrast, although a Longneck can have up to 3 tokens from the excess food pile, a Longneck can only take in as many tokens as its populations or fat tissue can consume. ]

Rules say [page 11]:  "A Scavenger eats 1 Food from the Excess Food pile every time a Carnivore attacks, even if the Scavenger is getting attacked or doing the attacking.  Food scavenged when it is not your turn will stay on your Population cards until the end of your next turn."

AND

Rules also say [Step 3, Rule 2, page 8]:  "...If there is Food on that card (see Scavenger Trait, p.11), place it in the Food Bag of the attacked player."

The way we are playing is that if the Scavenger has a bunch of food tokens, if the Scavenger gets attacked/made extinct before its turn comes around, ALL those food tokens get dumped in Scavenger's food bag, regardless if the Scavenger has sufficient population / fat tissue to "take in" all that food 
[because of the rule on p.8], 
BUT 
if it comes around to the Scavenger's own turn, then the Scavenger has to DEAL with that food by adding sufficient population or fat tissue to absorb all that food before it can "earn" all those tokens (put them in the bag) 
[based on rule on p.11].

Are we doing this right?

Comment: You might want to consider formatting this better with some paragraphs because as it is now it is very hard to read.'

Comment: You can never eat more than your population (unless you have Fat Tissue)

Comment: The rules seem to suggest an exception to this general rule about population and fat tissue.  On what rule do you base this answer?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only eat or scavenge as much food as you have population slots for. You simply do not collect food tokens after you reach that maximum, regardless of any further carnivore attacks.